# WebdriverIO 6: how to click on an element that is visible only after hovering

Tags: typescript, automation, webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO6 to create a demo on this site: `http://automationpractice.com/index.php`.
I am trying to do a "simple" scenario.

```
Feature: Dashboard
Test dashboard functionalities

Background: Open dashboard page
Given I visit home page

Scenario: Open Product Detail Page of the last product in the list
When I click on the last product in the list
Then Product Detail Page of the last product opens
```

When I try to click on "More" button of the last product in the list to open it's product details page, then I get `element not interactable` error.
This is what I have tried in the method that is trying to click the "More" button:

```
clickLastProductImage(productId: number) {
   browser.waitUntilListIsDisplayed(this.popularProducts, productId, 10000);
   const element = this.popularProductMoreButton(productId);
   console.log("in view port", element.isDisplayedInViewport()); // this results in false
   // element.scrollIntoView();
   element.moveTo();
   console.log("in view port", element.isDisplayedInViewport()); // BUT this also results in false 
   element.waitForDisplayed(); // this throws an error because the element is not displayed; without this 
                               // I get element not interactable error
   element.click();
 }
```

This is the selector of the element:

```
popularProductMoreButton(productId: number): WebdriverIO.Element {
return $('#homefeatured.product_list a.button.lnk_view[href*="id_product=' + productId + '"]');
}
```

Nothing I try works, it simply doesn't scroll to that element.
Is it a problem with the fact that the "More" button is visible only after hovering over the product image?
Here is the link to the source code on github: https://github.com/mareru/webdriverIO-shop-demo
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked. I had to first scrollIntoView and then move to the element that needed to be hovered (in this case it is the last product image). After than I had to click on "More" button.
This is the code that works:
Last product image selector:

```
productImage(productId: number): WebdriverIO.Element {
return $('#homefeatured.product_list a.product_img_link[href*="id_product=' + productId + '"]');
}
```

Method:

```
clickLastProductImage(productId: number) {
    browser.waitUntilListIsDisplayed(this.popularProducts, productId, 10000);

    const productImage = this.productImage(productId);
    productImage.scrollIntoView();
    productImage.moveTo();

    const element = this.popularProductMoreButton(productId);
    console.log("in view port", element.isDisplayedInViewport());
    element.waitForDisplayed();
    element.click();
}
```